# Application successfully installed but stops working when run in emulator

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator

I am trying to create a simple application that can sign in / sign up users . All the data are
stored in Mysql database .
My app was installed successfully but as I opened it, it gave an error saying "Unfortunately, 'myapp' has stop working".
I have read almost all related problems posted here but no luck!

here's from logcat .

```
07-25 01:22:31.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2101): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-25 01:22:31.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2101): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start         activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mysqltest/com.example.mobileapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
07-25 01:22:31.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
07-25 01:22:31.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at  android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
07-25 01:22:31.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-25 01:22:31.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
07-25 01:22:31.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-25 01:22:31.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-25 01:22:31.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
07-25 01:22:31.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-25 01:22:31.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-25 01:22:31.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
07-25 01:22:31.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-25 01:22:31.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-25 01:22:31.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2101): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
07-25 01:22:31.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
07-25 01:22:31.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
07-25 01:22:31.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
07-25 01:22:31.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
07-25 01:22:31.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
07-25 01:22:31.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
07-25 01:22:31.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
07-25 01:22:31.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
07-25 01:22:31.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
07-25 01:22:31.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at com.example.mobileapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:45)
07-25 01:22:31.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
07-25 01:22:31.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-25 01:22:31.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
07-25 01:22:31.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     ... 11 more
07-25 01:22:31.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2101): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-25 01:22:31.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
07-25 01:22:31.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
07-25 01:22:31.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
07-25 01:22:31.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     ... 23 more
07-25 01:22:31.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2101): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
07-25 01:22:31.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
07-25 01:22:31.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:503)
07-25 01:22:31.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:356)
07-25 01:22:31.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:800)
07-25 01:22:31.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2105)
07-25 01:22:31.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
07-25 01:22:31.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3364)
07-25 01:22:31.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3293)
07-25 01:22:31.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:453)
07-25 01:22:31.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:242)
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background" >



<TextView
android:id="@+id/tv2"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_above="@+id/password"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
android:text="Password" />  

<TextView
android:id="@+id/tv"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"  />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/tv0"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_above="@+id/tv1"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="38dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="PhilTaxWindow User Login"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/tv1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_above="@+id/username"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
android:text="Username" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/register"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/register"
android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/register" 
android:text="Don't Have an Account?"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"  />

<Button
android:id="@+id/Button01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_above="@+id/register"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
android:text="Login" />

<EditText
android:id="@+id/username"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_above="@+id/tv2"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
android:ems="10"
android:inputType="textPersonName"
android:singleLine="true" >

<requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
android:id="@+id/password"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_above="@+id/Button01"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
android:ems="10"
android:inputType="textPassword"
android:singleLine="true" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/register"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_above="@+id/tv"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
android:layout_marginRight="29dp"
android:text="Register here" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

mainactivity.java

```
package com.example.mobileapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.example.mysqltest.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{



private EditText Username, Password;
private Button Submit, Register;
private ProgressDialog Dialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://192.168.1.4/checkingPHP/CheckUser.php";
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    Password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    Submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    Register = (Button)findViewById(R.id.register);
    Submit.setOnClickListener(this);
    Register.setOnClickListener(this);

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.Button01:
            new AttemptLogin().execute();
        break;
    case R.id.register:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, Register.class);
            startActivity(i);
       break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    boolean failure = false;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        Dialog.setMessage("Validating...");
        Dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        Dialog.setCancelable(true);
        Dialog.show();
    }

    @Override

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        int success;
        String username = Username.getText().toString();
        String password = Password.getText().toString();

        try {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Username", username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", password));
            Log.d("request!", "starting");

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                   LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

            Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {

                Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WelcomPage.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(i);
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

            }else{
                Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        Dialog.dismiss();

        if (file_url != null){

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Checkout the logcat for application. And let me know the errors printed there.

Comment: Post the relevant code stacktrace without which how do you expect help?

Comment: Do u know how to get logcat output?

Comment: it means there is error in your application chek out logacat and show or copy paste your logcat here so we can give you answer

Comment: Application succesfully installed doesnt mean that your app will run successfully.There must be some exception.Post your logcat and relevant code.

Comment: Paste your xml file which you are inflating in onCreate of com.example.mobileapp.MainActivity

Comment: Paste your onCreate method from your MainActivity class.

Comment: emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.example.mobileapp.MainActivity activity launch'!

Comment: what causes with that stuff ?

Answer (score 0):

The emulator ran into out of memory exception

`Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` due to

```
android:background="@drawable/background"
```

The image that you are trying to load is causing this. Try reducing the image resolution.